# Query Syntax confirmation

Tags: android, sqlite

Is this syntax is correct to get Particular column from Table? Table name- FI_GOODS_DETAIL_TABLE, Column name- FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHGOODS...

"select " + FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHGOODS + "from " + FI_GOODS_DETAIL_TABLE + ";";

And am storing column values in arrray

```
public List<String> getAllLabels(){
            List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "select " + FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHGOODS + "from " + FI_GOODS_DETAIL_TABLE + ";";
            try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            } catch (Exception exe) {
                exe.printStackTrace();
                db.endTransaction();
                Log.e("Insertion failed",
                        "Transaction failure when inserting login data.");
                this.closeDatabase();
                Log.i("DB closed", "Database closed successfully.");
                errCode = "Err-DB-06";
                LogFileCreator.appendLog(errCode + " : " + exe.getMessage());
            }

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // closing connection
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

            // returning lables
            return labels;
        }
```

Comment: What makes you think that it's not correct syntax?

Comment: I dont getting values in my array

Comment: If it wasn't correct syntax you'd get an exception telling you so.

Comment: Btw, it seems there's a whitespace missing in `FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHGOODS + "from "` . It probably should be `+ " from "`.

Comment: Btw2, your code will not even compile like this - unless you have a non-local variable `cursor` too. And in that case, you have another bug.

Comment: Btw3: You're basically ignoring an exception, which you actually shouldn't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
    public List<String> getAllLabels() throws SQLiteException {
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "select " + FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHGOODS + " from " + FI_GOODS_DETAIL_TABLE ;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

          Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

          // looping through all rows and adding to list
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
          }

          cursor.close();

        } catch (RuntimeException exe) {

            exe.printStackTrace();

            this.closeDatabase(); // What does this do that db.close() does not?
            errCode = "Err-DB-06";
            LogFileCreator.appendLog(errCode + " : " + exe.getMessage());

            throw exe;

        } finally {
          db.close();
        }

        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }
```